# ¿Cómo leer un json con campos repetidos?

Tags: python, json

Tengo que leer un json de este tipo:

```
"song": {
    "0": {
        "artist": "aaa",
        "album": "bbb",
        ...
    },
    "1": {
        "artist": "aaa",
        "album": "bbb",
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

Necesito leer los valores dentro de los campos numéricos (`"0"`, `"1"`, etc.).

No doy con el modo de hacer un loop sin que se me produzca un `ErrorKey`. Como ejemplo, un código que he probando:

```py
r = requests.get("https://api.radioparadise.com/api/get_block?bitrate=4&info=true&chan=1")

for i in range(0, 8):
    artista = json.loads(r.text)["song"][str(i)]["artist"]
    print(artista)
    i += 1
```

Intenté con `while`, pero no sé como manejar el hecho que no sepa de antemano cuantos campos numéricos hay.

---

Me funciona así:

```py
for i in r.json()['song']:
    artista = json.loads(r.text)["song"][str(i)]["artist"]
    titulo = json.loads(r.text)["song"][str(i)]["title"]
    album = json.loads(r.text)["song"][str(i)]["album"]
    print("Tema", i)
    print("Artista:", artista)
    print("Canción:", titulo)
    print("Album:", album)
    print()
```

Pero no salen ordenados como en el json ¿Hay forma de que salgan en ese orden?

Comment: solo un punto, un json es un mapa y como tal es una mala práctica y no es aconsejable tener claves repetidas a lo largo del mapa. Y otra cosa, los campos 0, 1, 2 no tienen ningún sentido para representar una lista porque en json puedes y debes usar array para ese mismo caso. Tienes tantos problemas para iterar sobre el json por no usasr un array para recoger tu lista.

Answer (score 1):

No uses `range` para generar las claves sobre las que iterar, no sabes cuantas claves van a estar presentes en el diccionario para empezar. Esto causa que intentes acceder a claves que no existen o que dejes claves sin obtener porque tu rango es inferior. En tu solución recurres a manejar y silenciar el `KeyError`, pero esto aparte de complicarte sin necesidad es ineficiente (siempre iteras 8 veces aunque el diccionario tenga una sola clave) y, además, no evita que te puedas dejar claves sin visitar.

Puedes iterar sobre las claves de un diccionario sin preocuparte del número o de qué tipo de dato son con un simple `for- in`:

```
diccionario = {"1": "foo",
               "2": "bar"}

for key in diccionario:
    print(key, diccionario[key])
```

Aunque mejor generar una vista con `dict.items` para algo asi:

```
for key, value in diccionario.items():
    print(key, value)
```

En tu caso concreto, una forma muy simple de iterar sobre el diccionario que contiene las canciones (dado que las claves "0", "1", etc no te interesan por lo que comentas) es usar el método [`dict.values()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values), lo cual genera una vista que te permite iterar directamente sobre todos los valores contenidos en `json["song"]` con un ciclo `for-in`:

```
import requests


r = requests.get("https://api.radioparadise.com/api/get_block?bitrate=4&info=true&chan=1")

for song in r.json()["song"].values():
    titulo = song["title"]
    artista = song["artist"]
    album = song["album"]

    print(f'Título: {titulo}\nArtista: {artista}\nAlbum: {album}\n')  # Solo Python >= 3.6
    # print('Título:', titulo,'\nArtista:', artista, '\nAlbum:', album,'\n')
```

**Edición:**

Si se usa Python >= 3.6 los diccionarios mantiene el orden de inserción, pero no lo hacen en versiones anteriores de Python. Si deseas que los diccionarios mantengan el orden de sus items igual que en el json original lo más simple es forzar a `json.load`/`json.loads` a usar c`ollections.OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import json
import requests



r = requests.get("https://api.radioparadise.com/api/get_block?bitrate=4&info=true&chan=1")
data = json.loads(r.text, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)

for song in data["song"].values():
    titulo = song["title"]
    artista = song["artist"]
    album = song["album"]

    #print(f'Título: {titulo}\nArtista: {artista}\nAlbum: {album}\n')  # Solo Python >= 3.6
    print 'Título:', titulo,'\nArtista:', artista, '\nAlbum:', album,'\n' #
```

Comment: Gracias, me son de mucha utilidad, de a poco voy entendiendo.

Answer (score 0):

Lo resolví así:

```
for i in range (0,8):

        try:
            artista = json.loads(r.text)["song"][str(i)]["artist"]
            titulo = json.loads(r.text)["song"][str(i)]["title"]
            album = json.loads(r.text)["song"][str(i)]["album"]
            print ("Artista:"," ",(artista))
            print ("Canción:"," ",(titulo))
            print ("Album:"," ",(album))
            print(""
                )
            i+=1
        except:
                pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Si te sirve, para mostrarlo directamente con las claves que tiene el propio JSON podría hacer algo así:

```
 for i in r.json()['song']:
    for x in json['song'][i]:
       print(str(x)+': '+str(json['song'][i][x]))
```

También usando las cabeceras como has puesto, lo puedes hacer así:

```
for i in r.json()['song']:
   print('Artista: '+str(json['song'][i]['artist']))
   print('Título: '+str(json['song'][i]['title']))
   print('Album: '+str(json['song'][i]['album']))
```

Un saludo!